# How to use an sql subquery that uses count

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I have a system where reservations are stored as records in one table(workshop_reservation) and sessions (the things being reserved) are stored in another table(session). Each reservation belongs to a session, and each session belongs to a workshop.

I want to make a mysql query that finds the number of reservations for each session that belongs to a certain workshop. I was trying to use count() to find the number of reservations in a given session, and this query works fine for that purpose (# is the session number):

```
SELECT count( r.id )
FROM workshop_reservation AS `r`
WHERE r.session_id = #
```

I want to figure out how to perform this query for every session. I can easily find every session_id using the following query:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM session AS `s`
```

My problem is combining these, because when any of the sessions have no reservations, no row is printed for that session. Instead, I want it to print a 0 in the count column for sessions that have no reservations. The following query works fine for sessions that have at least one reservation, but it ignores sessions that have no reservations (doesn't print a row saying 0).

```
SELECT count( r.id ) , r.session_id
FROM workshop_reservation AS `r`
WHERE r.session_id
IN (
SELECT s.id
FROM session AS `s`
WHERE s.workshop_id =1
)
AND r.reservation_status_id =0
GROUP BY r.session_id
```

How can I force it to print a row with a 0 in it in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I should put this here instead of choosing one of your answers, since neither of them quite worked alone. I used elements from both (mostly mdma with one line from nico). Here is the query that does exactly what I want:

```
SELECT session.id, count( workshop_reservation.id )
FROM session LEFT JOIN workshop_reservation ON session.id = workshop_reservation.session_id
AND workshop_reservation.reservation_status_id =0
GROUP BY session.id
```

I don't know how obvious this is to SQL experts, but if the AND is changed to WHERE, the reservation_status_id is actually ignored.

Comment: Sorry scott, I think that was actually a typo on my part... what if you use `HAVING` instead? I think the problem is that `WHERE` doesn't work with `COUNT`.

Comment: Using HAVING instead of AND makes a syntax error. I'm not sure I know what you mean. Using WHERE just results in every reservation for the session being counted, regardless of its reservation_status_id.

Comment: sorry, forget about what I said about `HAVING`... it's not true actually, I did not remember correctly. As for the WHERE/AND problem, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a subquery. You can use a simple GROUP BY which will return 0 when there are no reservations for the given session, or the number of reservations.

```
SELECT s.id, count( r.id )
FROM session AS 's' LEFT JOIN workshop_reservation AS `r`
ON s.id=r.session_id
GROUP BY s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `JOIN`

For instance

```
SELECT COUNT( r.id ) , r.session_id
FROM workshop_reservation r
LEFT JOIN sessions s ON r.session_id = s.id
AND r.reservation_status_id =0
GROUP BY r.session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.*, count(wr.id) as num from sessions as s 
  left join workshop_reservation as wr on wr.session_id = s.id
group by s.id
```